# SQL Update half of each distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some records I'm moving from one table to another with some manipulation.

I've put them in a temp table so I can do the manipulation. Specifically, I need to change the half of a distinct value on a column to something, then change the other half to something else:

In my temp table I have

```
Animals | SeveralOtherColumns
dog
cat 
fish
dog
dog
dog
fish
cat 
cat 
cat
```

and I need to have

```
Animals | SeveralOtherColumns
dog_A
cat_A
fish_A
dog_A
dog_B
dog_B
fish_B
cat_A
cat_B
cat_B
```

I don't know what distinct values will be in `Animals`, or how many of each distinct value there will be.

So my initial thought is:

```
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Animals)) FROM #temptable)

--this throws an error, doesn't like the assignment 
SET @animals = (SELECT DISTINCT(Animals) FROM #temptable)

WHILE (@count > 0)
BEGIN
    -- about here is where I'm lost
    -- update the first half of the distinct value
    UPDATE #temptable SET #temptable.Animals = #temptable.Animals + '_A'
    WHERE Animals = @animals[@count] --Pretty sure this won't work but gets the point across
    FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT FROM #temptable)

    -- update the remaining set of that distinct value
    UPDATE #temptable SET #temptable.Animals = #temptable.Animals + '_B'
    WHERE Animals = @animals[@count]
    FROM #temptable


    SET @count = @count - 1
END
```

Comment: what's the logic behind the suffixes?, I don't get it

Comment: do you need any sql server compatibility, or latest version is your target?

Comment: @Lamak First half of each distinct value gets _A appended, the rest get _B appended. Kind of weird to explain in human language...

Comment: @infiniteRefactor 2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NTILE()`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = NTILE(2) OVER(PARTITION BY Animals ORDER BY Animals)
    FROM dbo.Animals
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Animals = Animals + CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN '_A' ELSE '_B' END
;
```

Comment: I forgot about `NTILE()` - I like this method a lot better!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a single [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and checking the [`mod` (`%2`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) to divide them into equal groups:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *, 
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Animals Order By Animals) As RN
    From    #TempTable
)
Update  Cte
Set     Animals = Animals + Case When RN % 2 = 0 
                                Then '_A' 
                                Else '_B' 
                            End
```